# Changing expires index with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using the following schema to store some user tokens which should expire after a certain amount of time (30 minutes in this case):

```
var Schema = require('mongoose').Schema;
var tokenSchema = mongoose.Schema({ 
    email: { type: String, required: true, trim: true }, 
    token: { type: String, required: true }, 
    created: { type: Date, expires: 60*30, default: Date.now },
}, {strict: 'throw'});

module.exports = mongoose.model('tokens', tokenSchema);
```

Now if I start my node.js application, I can check MongoDBfor the indexes on this collection using `db.getCollection('tokens').getIndexes()`. This results in:

```
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "node-android.resettokens"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "created" : 1
        },
        "name" : "created_1",
        "ns" : "node-android.resettokens",
        "expireAfterSeconds" : 1800,
        "background" : true,
        "safe" : null
    }
]
```

If I now shut down my node app, change the value of expires in the token schema to something different (an hour for example), restart my node app and check the collection indexes again, I end up having the same result. I noticed this behavior after setting the TTL feature to 10 seconds for the first time to test its workings, and later finding that changing the expires value still made my documents get deleted very quickly.

So my question is: is there a way to automatically overwrite the old expires index with a new one, or do I have to delete it myself? I the latter is the case, is there a way to do this in mongoose, or do I have to execute a `db.getCollection('tokens').dropIndex('created_1')` via the mongo shell myself?